# What are the combination pairs in Heroes of Dragon Age?

Tags: heroes-of-dragon-age

In Heroes of Dragon Age by combining hero cards, you can increase a hero’s XP and stat potential. Identical combine tiers grant a 10% XP bonus.

Can you only combine identical cards or are their combination pairs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine identical cards with different tiers. You just get extra XP when they are on the same tier.

That being said there are some downsides to combining this way. For example combining 2 pair of tier 2 identical cards will produce a tier 3 card, not tier 4.

More explanation in this link: ["Wikia: Heroes of Dragon Age Combining"](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Heroes_of_Dragon_Age#Combining)